# WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/Forms/fesm5/forms.js There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: angular7

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/Forms/fesm5/forms.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* E:\Ecommerse App Angular\12-06-19 DATEPIKER\my-app\node_modules\@angular\Forms\fesm5\forms.js
    Used by 18 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Ecommerse App Angular\12-06-19 DATEPIKER\my-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\Ecommerse App Angular\12-06-19 DATEPIKER\my-app\src\app\app.module.ts
* E:\Ecommerse App Angular\12-06-19 DATEPIKER\my-app\node_modules\@angular\forms\fesm5\forms.js
    Used by 11 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Ecommerse App Angular\12-06-19 DATEPIKER\my-app\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\fesm5\ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js
```

I was getting these  warnings when I compile angular app ,every thing working and when I use `npm start` command it was giving these compile time warnings.In my app I used angular Template Driven Forms,Reactive forms along with I used Ngx-Bootstrap components `MODEL` and `BsDatepicker`.When I install  `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save` it was giving above warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the package reference and reinstall using npm install @angular/forms.